# Database linking using php

Tags: php

I am getting an error in my php code for database linking.I am trying to link my website login page with my database hosted on server.Here is the code

**init.php**

```
 <?php
     define('HOST','##########');
     define('USER','##########');
     define('PASS','##########');
     define('DB','##########');

     $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');


    ?>       
 <?php
            require "init.php";
             $username = $_POST["username"];
             $password = $_POST["password"];
             $fullname = $_POST["fullname"];
             $sex = $_POST["sex"];
             $country = $_POST["country"];
             $address = $_POST["address"];
             $contact = $_POST["contact"];
             $email = $_POST["email"];
             $dob = $_POST["dob"];
             $flag = $_POST["flag"];
             $sql = "insert into signup('".$username."','".$password."','".$fullname."','".$sex."','".$country."','".$address."','".$contact."','".$email."','".$dob."','".$flag."');";
             if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
             { echo"<br><h3>One row inserted....</h3>"; }
             else
             {   echo "Error in insertion...." . mysqli_error($con);
             }
             ?>
```

> ERROR
>                   Error in insertion....You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near ''','','','','','','','','','')' at
>   line 1

Comment: "I am getting an error in my php code for database linking" => what error?

Comment: I have updated the  code,still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your insert query should be like:

```
$sql = "insert into signup values('".$username."','".$password."','".$fullname."','".$sex."','".$country."','".$address."','".$contact."','".$email."','".$dob."','".$flag."');";
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed **VALUES** in insert query. And use bind_param() to bind the values in query instead of directly including.

```
 $sql = "insert into signup VALUES('".$username."','".$password."','".$fullname."','".$sex."','".$country."','".$address."','".$contact."','".$email."','".$dob."','".$flag."');";
```